# An archive widget, coming from nowhere on my posts and pages

Tags: widgets, archives

Pretty much, it looks like this:

[image]

And I really do not know where the "Acrhive" is coming from. This is how the Widget page looks like (either this way or the archive is set on the bottom):

[image]

obviously the "Archive" is not in wordpress. The theme is "Responsive", version 3.11.

Any ideas how to fix it? This is the site:
https://www.vitoshacademy.com/cryptography-in-python/

Comment: most likely some default coding in your theme - please check with the developer of your theme or ask in the support forum of your theme.

Comment: @Michael - this default coding was not there some days ago and I have not updated for years. Anyway, I am using a free theme of "Responsive", thus the dev probably would not support.

Comment: the theme should be supported in https://wordpress.org/support/theme/responsive - depending on your latest changes to the settings and used widgets, the 'archive' might automatically get shown in the sidebar.

Comment: If you recently updated the theme, it may have changed some defaults. It might be in Right Sidebar. You might need to look through the files - this is actually appearing on your "category" page, not Posts or Pages - so look in `category.php` or `archive.php` to figure out which sidebar is being included.